# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on 'angular2/platform/browser'

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

Visual Studio 2015 update 1
TypeScript 1.7
Angular2 beta

I'm trying to create an angular2 demo and I can't seem to get things working just right.

I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" on the "import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';" at runtime.

Here is my solution on github
https://github.com/robertdunaway/katas-angular2/tree/master/001%20Angular2%20-%20getting%20started/after/src/vs2015-TS

Comment: You are missing the `System` configuration. Check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: This is what I'm missing.  Thank you.

How do I mark this question as answered so you get credit?

Comment: You can't accept a comment, I'll put it as an answer. Just click the check mark below the number with the arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `System` configuration. Check: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart